# Getting Rid of Decimal place in Java?

Tags: java, decimal, bigdecimal

I am reading in java inputs in format below

```
2499.873639
32.374242
0.610059
...
```

Now i want to get rid of the decimal place and have them in this format

```
2499873639
32374242
610059
...
```

I have this code which does it for smaller number for not for larger numbers. The Larger numbers become negative (i think this overflowing) and giving it junk values.

```
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(a).multiply(new BigDecimal("1000000.")
```

If i increase the 0's by another two

```
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(a).multiply(new BigDecimal("100000000.")
```

It works for larger numbers but not smaller numbers. In short of having a bunch of if's is there anyway to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(a.toString().replace('.', ''));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String formattedInput = (String.valueOf(input)).replace(".", "");
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert the double to String, if it is not.  
Then use `String.replace('.', '');`  
Then Convert back to int or long, if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with String replacement functions.

```
public static BigDecimal noDecimal(BigDecimal b) {
    return new BigDecimal(b.toPlainString().replace(".", ""));
}
```

If you already have a String rather than a BigDecimal, this can be simplified to this:

```
public static BigDecimal noDecimal(String s) {
    return new BigDecimal(s.replace(".", ""));
}
```